# python-binance package suddenly giving ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I have been using the [python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance) package for over a year now without any problem. An hour ago I suddenly get `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to import the package somewhere in my scripts, which were running smoothly before.
I updated the package using pip and checked the git repository for any changes but could not find any.

I tried this using python 3.8.10 and 3.8.12.

So what I did is `pip install python-binance --upgrade` to update the package.

The following code was working before and now gives the error:

```
from binance.client import Client
```

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Comment: According to the header of github (near readme) it is supported in Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. In both env where I tested this I had created a new python file named `binance.py` which caused this error. Unfortunately the error message was a bit unclear here. Deleted the file and it is working now.